# How to append name of folder to files inside with Shell script?

Tags: zsh, automator

I'm creating a Folder Action (Automator Mac) that processes new folders. My code does the first part. It trims the name of the dropped folder to 8 characters. Now it needs to append the trimmed folder name to all of the files inside and move the files up a level (where the folder was dropped). Finally, it needs to delete the empty folder.

### Automator > Run Shell Script

- shell: `/bin/zsh`
- pass input: as arguments

```sh
for f in "$@"; do
  autoload zmv // not sure where to put this
  if [[ $f == *""* ]]; then // currently set to be unfiltered
    filename=$f:t
    filepath=$f:h
    dest=$(echo $filename | cut -c1-8) // var of dropped folder name. first 8 chars
    mv $filepath/{"$filename","$dest"} // trims dropped folder to 8 chars
    zmv '(**/)(*).png' 't_$1$2.png' // this doesnt work here, BUT works in terminal. "t_" is temporary
  fi
done
```

Why doesn't the zmv command seem work in the shell script? OR Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you have `--` in front of `zmv`? And why does your file start with `--  /bin/zhs  pass inputs as parameters`? Should the latter perhaps be `#!/bin/zsh` ? Or is this some kind of copy-paste error?

Comment: I don't know. I'm trying to learn.

Comment: You didn’t write the code yourself?

Comment: I wrote the code, Marlon. I just said I was learning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a "dry run" version of your script first, so we can see what's going on (and ensure we don't "accidentally the whole thing"):

```sh
autoload -Uz zmv
local file suffix
print "PWD=$PWD" >| ~/Desktop/log       # >| overwrites
print 'args:' "$@:a" >>| ~/Desktop/log  # >>| appends
for file in "$@:a"; do
  if [[ -d $file ]]; then
    suffix="${(r:8:)file:t}"
    zmv -n $file'/(*)' ${file:h:h}'/$1$suffix' >>| ~/Desktop/log
    # rm $file
  fi
done
```

I apply this folder action to the folder `~/Desktop/test`. I then drop another folder into it. Here's what output I then get in the file `~/Desktop/log`:

```sh
PWD=/Users/marlon
args: /Users/marlon/Desktop/test/Be-Bop-a-Lula
mv -- /Users/marlon/Desktop/test/Be-Bop-a-Lula/foo /Users/marlon/Desktop/fooBe-Bop-a
```

As you can see, the present working directory is set to my *home folder,* not the folder on which the folder action is acting. That's why your `zmv` statement didn't work correctly.

Here is then the "for real" version of the script:

```sh
autoload -Uz zmv  # Dependencies are normally put at the top.
local file suffix  # Good practice to restrict vars to local scope.
for file in "$@:a"; do  # Ensure we have absolute file paths.
  if [[ -d $file ]]; then  # Check if $file is a directory.
    suffix="${(r:8:)file:t}"  # Trim to 8 characters.
    zmv $file'/(*)' ${file:h:h}'/$1$suffix'
    rm -r $file
  fi
done
```